# Kafka Consumer Group Metadata

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka Version 2.4.1
Zookeeper 3.4.10

I am having trouble deleting a consumer group created by kafka streams application. Even though the application is down, but the group always report it as 'rebalancing' state.  And kafka-consumer-groups doesn't allow me to delete it as it says 'The group is not empty'

Refer: 
[Consumer group stuck in 'rebalancing' even though there are no consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61526206/consumer-group-stuck-in-rebalancing-even-though-there-are-no-consumers)

Questions:

1. Where is consumer group information stored ?  ( I tried zkcli.sh command and /consumers is empty)
2. Where does group coordinator store information related to consumer & its state
3. Is there other commands which can be used to query the group information ( or any hack)
4. Where are consumer group members stored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to list all consumer groups

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --list
```

---

Now to get information about a specific consumer group you can simply run

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
    --describe \
    --group my-consumer-group
```

---

> 4. Where are consumer group members stored ?

The metadata of consumer groups are stored in internal topic [`__consumer_offsets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529511/what-is-the-use-of-consumer-offsets-and-schema-topics-in-kafka).